# Decoupling CardLayout Panels

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

Would like to get your opinions on the best way of decoupling CardLayout panels. Right now I'm using a holder panel which looks like:

```
class CardHolder extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
```

Then the sub panels are:

```
class SubPanel extends JPanel {
    private List<ActionListener> listeners;
    private void fireActionListeners(ActionEvent e) {
        for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.actionPerformed(e);
        }
    }
```

When I add the SubPanel to the CardHolder I add it as an ActionListener. Then when a button is pressed on the SubPanel I propagate the action event by sending the event to all of the listeners attached (i.e. the CardHolder).

Is this sort of method acceptable? Or am I missing something else?

I looked at using the observer pattern but it doesn't seem to be correct here as the SubPanel doesn't change state, only a button was pressed which expects something to happen.

Comment: The thing is, why do you need to notify the `CardHolder` panel? And most important, what are you developing? Is it a [wizard](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html)? Some context will be useful to get better help sooner.

Comment: It is a wizard of sorts, but the path they take through the wizard will change depending on options they choose, in this case there is a change in the screen depending on whether the user is importing or exporting data with the wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It is a wizard of sorts, but the path they take through the wizard will change depending on options they choose, in this case there is a
>   change in the screen depending on whether the user is importing or
>   exporting data with the wizard.*

Well in this case I think an approach like described in [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/wizard-136789.html) it's a better design choice than adding `ActionListeners` to your card holder.

The key is having a wizard model to keep the relevant data that has to be filled during the wizard process. This model must have a mechanism to notify when its data has changed in order to let card holder know that something happened and it needs to react in consequence (i.e.: changing the cards flow, replacing the cards as needed, making cards get updated, etc). Of course your cards should have access to modify the model through getters/setters because are these that will modify the model, not the card holder.

The simplest way to implement a notification chain from the model would be using [PropertyChangeSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeSupport.html) as exemplified below. An even more flexible mechanism would be creating your own `ModelEvent` and `ModelListener` but is up to you decide if it's worth to go that far.

#### Example

Here is a really simple model. Cards should update this model and card holder should subscribe a `PropertyChangeListener` to listen for property changes (i.e.: "type" property).

```
public enum Type {
    IMPORT, EXPORT
}

public class WizardModel {

    private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;
    private Type type;

    public WizardModel() {
        super();
        this.type = Type.IMPORT;
        this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type newType) {
        Type oldType = this.type;
        this.type = newType;
        firePropertyChangeEvent(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, "type", oldType, newType));
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    protected void firePropertyChangeEvent(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        for (PropertyChangeListener l : propertyChangeSupport.getPropertyChangeListeners(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            l.propertyChange(evt);
        }
    }
}
```